# In 2023, Are there COVID testing requirements for US citizens re-entering the US via air?

Tags: usa, air-travel, covid-19, us-citizens, event-based-effects

As of January 24, 2023, are there any COVID-19 testing requirements for US citizens flying back to the US from abroad? The [CDC page](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/international-travel-during-covid19.html) on the topic is very confusing with lots of clauses for travel from certain places (China) and non-US citizens, and doesn't state clearly whether US citizens not affected by those clauses need test results to board.

Aside from just a yes/no answer, I'd like a link to an official source or reputable third party stating it clearly.

Comment: It depends where you’re travelling *from*. The map on the IATA site https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php has a list of entry restrictions

Comment: @Traveller: Sorry, but that map feels useless. It just shows most of the world as "partially restrictive" which really doesn't help.

Comment: @Hilmar Clicking on the country for which information is sought gives a detailed list of restrictions. Hard to prove a negative. If neither the IATA site nor the CDC page is good enough for the OP I really don’t know what else might be :-)

Comment: @Traveller: My apologies. That's actually super helpful, I didn't realize you can click on the country.!! Thanks

Comment: Who closed this as duplicate?!? The supposed duplicate is from a completely different time (start of the pandemic) and has no relevance to this.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE The duplicate was indeed originally posted some time ago, but its answer is a "community wiki" which is regularly updated; the information there is current and contains links to official sources.

Comment: @mlc: OK, I guess that kinda works..

Answer (score 3):

The CDC page states :

> ALL TRAVELERS
>
> > This page is for all international travelers including U.S. citizens, U.S. nationals, U.S. lawful permanent residents, immigrants, and non-U.S. citizens who are not U.S. immigrants.

All the restrictions, except the COVID Vaccination requirement, are to be applied to everyone

---

As of 2023-01-24, the requirements are :

> ALL travelers 2 years and older: If you are flying to the U.S. from China, Hong Kong, or Macau, or have been in these areas in the past 10 days and are flying from certain airports, you are required to show a negative COVID-19 test result or documentation of recovery from COVID-19 before you board your flight to the U.S.

There are no in force testing requirements for US Citizens/LPR

Comment: So *are* there testing requirements?

Comment: What @lambshaanxy asked. This is a non-answer as written. I agree with the analysis but there is no information as to whether "all restrictions" includes any testing requirement for those not coming from China.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE If it isn't on that page, there are no further restrictions

Comment: Did you mean to say: *There are no in force testing requirements for US Citizens/LPR unless you're traveling from China*?

Comment: Modulo @JonathanReez's correcting I suspect this is correct, but the difficulty there seems to have been pinning this down is... not reassuring.

Comment: Sounds like the vague governmenteze has been perfected to the point of allowing them to do whatever the heck they want based on how someone feels like enforcing a rule that day.